# No sé que estoy haciendo concretamente en el codigo

Tags: c#

Hola no sé muy bien que estoy haciendo ‘aclaro código si funciona’ 
Lo que no entiendo es esto `byte[] a = new byte[64]`
Por  lo que se byte es un array de bytes
Si lo dejo así `byte[] a = new byte[]` me da error 
el `dtImg` es un `DataTable` donde tengo guardado las img

```
byte[] a = new byte[64];
a = (byte[])dtImg.Rows[0][1];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(a);
pbx_ImgVale.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
pbx_ImgVale.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Error es:

> La creación de matriz debe disponer de un tamaño de matriz o un inicializador de matriz

Si lo dejo asi

```
byte[] a = new byte[];
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad esa instrucción te sobra.

Lo que está haciendo el código es crear una variable `a` de tipo array de bytes

```
byte[] a
```

e inicializándola con un array vacío de 64 posiciones:

```
= new byte[64];
```

En la siguiente instrucción asigna a la variable `a` el contenido del segundo campo (índice `1`) de la primera fila (índice `0`) del `DataTable`.

```
a = (byte[])dtImg.Rows[0][1];
```

Con lo que el valor anterior (el array vacío) no se utiliza. Podrías reemplazarlo por:

```
byte[] a = (byte[])dtImg.Rows[0][1];
```

El resto del código sirve para crear un objeto `Image` a partir del array de bytes del campo del `DataTable` y asignárselo al `PictureBox`.

Comment: Gracias me aclaro la duda si eso lo que me sugirió lo acabo de hacer Gracias.